# Can an affirmation be negative?

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage, negation

> 1. I'm angry.
> 2. I'm *not* angry.

Are both (1) and (2) *affirmations*?

I ask because Merriam-Webster defines *affirmation* as 'a positive assertion', so this make me confused as to whether (2), which technically is a negative assertion, is an *affirmation*.

Comment: I would call (2) a denial, not an affirmation, at least by itself. In a conversation, either one could be an affirmation or a denial.

Comment: Google Books claims 57,000 instances of *"He [affirmed that he was **not**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22affirmed+that+he+was+not%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [angry, or whatever he wasn't]"*

Comment: Consider these as answers, and you'll have a real answer: "*Yes, an affirmation can never be negative.*" versus "*No, an affirmation can never be negative.*" (Hint: @Lumberjack and context)

Comment: Je t'aime ... moi non plus

Comment: "Yeah, right." for instance

Answer (score 15):

I would say that the answer relies on ***[context](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/context)***.  Lets take the following conversations as a case study.

*"Hey Joe, how are you doing?  You look like you've calmed down a lot since that fight."*

*"Yeah, I'm not angry anymore.  Thanks for talking me down last night."*

I would argue that in the example above "I'm not angry" is an affirmation due to the context of the statement.  It affirms the previous statement as being true.  Let us consider a counter example.

*"Hey Joe, how are you doing?  You look really angry."*

*"No, I'm not angry.  I'm just feeling a little hungover."*

In this example "I'm not angry" is not an affirmation, rather it negates the statement preceding it.

Whether or not a statement is affirmative relies on the context in which it is stated.  There are cases where a negative statement can be either affirmative or negative in context.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the use of the word positive is not meant to suggest that an affirmation always has a "positive tone" so much as that it is positive in nature - as in "I am positive that I am right." and "I am positive that you are wrong!". As such I would say the answer is yes, an affirmation can have a negative tone.

Comment: You are not wrong - is that an affirmation then ;)

Comment: That is not only an affirmation - it is also a truism :)

Answer (score 2):

Another relevant datum is the definition of [*affirm*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affirm):

> 1. To declare positively or firmly; maintain to be true.
> 2. To support or uphold the validity of; confirm.

It can simply mean any definite statement. I can, for example, *affirm* that I am not an alien.

Comment: +1, but you are affirming that "I am not an alien" is true, which, strictly speaking, is different from saying that "I am not an alien" is an *affirmation*, though.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo I am saying that it is actually. An affirmation (to me at least) is a statement that is made with certainty. It can also mean a _yes_ but it does not need to. It's a strange word, but you should not confuse _affirmative_ with _affirmation_.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo to make matters worse, one of the [definitions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/positive) of _positive_ is " Admitting of no doubt; irrefutable". I believe that is the meaning used in the definition of _affirmation_ that you cited. Also see the definition [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affirmative): "Giving assent or approval; confirming". It is the _confirming_ aspect that is important to this question.